# I got error with in Swift 2 "Type 'NSCalendarUint' has no member 'YearCalendarUnit' "?

Tags: ios9, swift2

I am trying to read data using HealthKit but keeping getting some issues when I run this code:

```
do {
    let birthDay = try healthKitStore.dateOfBirth()
    let today = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let differenceComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(.YearCalendarUnit, fromDate: birthDay, toDate: today, options: NSCalendarOptions(0) )
    age = differenceComponents.year
} catch {
    print("Error reading Birthday: \(error)")
}
```

The error is

> Type 'NSCalendarUint' has no member 'YearCalendarUnit'

Answer (score 2):

```
let differenceComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.Year, fromDate: birthDay, toDate: today, options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))
```

`NSCalendarUnit` is a struct type.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>⌥</kbd>-click on `NSCalendar` and scroll down. At the bottom of the page you'll see the `NSCalendarUnit` OptionSetType.

All values have been changed to a more convenient value like `.Year`, `.Day`, `.Hour`